# topic modelling, literature. Beginner

Tags: r

I am totally beginner in programming and R.
I am trying to apply the topic modelling on three literature books. I try to do it having as example Silge's and Robinson's example (Text mining with R, chapter 6), with the difference that i use no preexistent list of books but a choice of mine.
I meet problems, even when i applied the given code in the example i mentioned above.

I downloaded packages (gutenbergr, tidytext, stringr, topicmodels, dplyr, tidyr)  and books, and have tried to create a separate object "books" guided by the console output. I want to run the analysis by book, but i found code examples only by chapter. So i tried this:

```
library(gutenbergr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(topicmodels)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


                                        
wuthering_heights <- gutenberg_download(768, mirror = "http://mirrors.xmission.com/gutenberg/")                                     
utopia <- gutenberg_download(2130, mirror = "http://mirrors.xmission.com/gutenberg/")
the_grand_inquisitor <- gutenberg_download(8578, mirror = "http://mirrors.xmission.com/gutenberg/")


titles <- c("Wuthering Heights", "Utopia", "The Grand Inquisitor")
books <- gutenberg_works(title %in% titles) %>%
  gutenberg_download(meta_fields = "title")

books <- list(wuthering_heights, utopia, the_grand_inquisitor)
    
    by_chapter = books %>%
      group_by(title) %>%
      mutate(chapter = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^chapter ", ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>% # ignore the word chapter
      ungroup() %>%
      filter(chapter > 0) %>%
      unite(document, title, chapter)
    
    by_chapter_word = by_chapter %>%
      unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

I receive in console: that "ungroup" method can´t be applied for objects of class "list", it can´t find the object chapter, it can´t find the "ungroup" method.

any tips are welcome,
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `books` as dataframe and then you can use the functions on it. You can try :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

books <- lst(wuthering_heights, moby_dick, great_expectations)

bind_rows(books, .id = 'books') %>%
  unnest_tokens('word', 'text') %>%
  filter(!word %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  count(books, word) %>%
  group_by(books) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 10) -> top10words

top10words

#   books                word           n
#   <chr>                <chr>      <int>
# 1 the_grand_inquisitor thou         104
# 2 the_grand_inquisitor thee          61
# 3 the_grand_inquisitor thy           51
# 4 the_grand_inquisitor bread         28
# 5 the_grand_inquisitor freedom       28
# 6 the_grand_inquisitor hast          24
# 7 the_grand_inquisitor god           22
# 8 the_grand_inquisitor inquisitor    19
# 9 the_grand_inquisitor earth         18
#10 the_grand_inquisitor weak          18
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I receive: Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `title` doesn't exist., Error: object 'by_chapter' not found , Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.   * Column `title` is not found. I just put your piece of code without changes after mine, which downloaded properly the books with their ID from an active mirror site. Could it be a mistake of mine?

Comment: @Maryvs80 I think the download issue is from my end. Although, I cannot figure out why I cannot download the data. Can you edit your post with `dput(books)` ? Is it too big to post it here? Is there any other way to share data?

Comment: Yes, that now works for me and I can download the data. However, can you specify what is it that you want to do? I see each of that data has only two columns `gutenberg_id` and `text` but in your code you are grouping by `title` which is not a column in the data hence you get the error. Can you tell what is your overall goal here? @Maryvs80

Comment: @ Ronak Shah I re-entered my initial code having changed the books. After  `books <-list` I inserted and tested your piece

Comment: I want to extract the top 3 main topics and their top ten terms for each book, and then visualize them with ggplot. I let the chapters aside, too complicated for me

Comment: Every post should ask and answer only one specific question. If you have additional questions you can ask it as a new question. I am not sure how to get topics from text but I updated the answer to show you have to get top 10 words from each book. Also just for reference I am using `lst` function which is different from `list` and it is not a typo.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great push. Really, i didn´t mention  all the steps i want to do, trying to solve them in this post. And i am sorry for the `lst`, i just couldn´t imagine that existed something so similar with `list`